# Flutter: How to call audio_service Handler from a static method?

Tags: flutter

I have an audio handler:

```
/// An [AudioHandler] for playing a single item.
class AudioPlayerHandler extends BaseAudioHandler with SeekHandler {

  late MediaItem _item;

  late final AudioPlayer _player;

  static final AudioPlayerHandler instance = AudioPlayerHandler._privateConstructor();
  static AudioPlayer? _audioPlayer;

  AudioPlayerHandler._privateConstructor();

  Future<AudioPlayer> get audioPlayer async{
    if(_audioPlayer != null){
      return _audioPlayer!;
    }
    _audioPlayer = await _init(static: true);
    return _audioPlayer!;
  }

  _init({bool static = false}) async {
    // pl.play(aud.AssetSource("audio/song2.mp3"));
    // So that our clients (the Flutter UI and the system notification) know
    // what state to display, here we set up our audio handler to broadcast all
    // playback state changes as they happen via playbackState...
    // _player.setAsset('song1.mp3');
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    final assetFile = File(tempDir.path+"/testFile.mp3"); // where you want to extract the asset to - typically the cache/temporary dir

    await assetFile.writeAsBytes((await rootBundle.load("assets/audio/song2.mp3")).buffer.asUint8List());
    // Wait a bit after writing the file to give Flutter a chance to "actually" write it.
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    if(static){
      // _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()..setFilePath(assetFile.path);
      // _audioPlayer!.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);
    } else{
      _player = AudioPlayer()..setFilePath(assetFile.path);
      _player.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);
    }
  }
  /// Initialise our audio handler.
  AudioPlayerHandler() {
    _init();
  }

  // In this simple example, we handle only 4 actions: play, pause, seek and
  // stop. Any button press from the Flutter UI, notification, lock screen or
  // headset will be routed through to these 4 methods so that you can handle
  // your audio playback logic in one place.

  @override
  Future<void> play() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> pause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  @override
  Future<void> stop() => _player.stop();

  /// Transform a just_audio event into an audio_service state.
  ///
  /// This method is used from the constructor. Every event received from the
  /// just_audio player will be transformed into an audio_service state so that
  /// it can be broadcast to audio_service clients.
  PlaybackState _transformEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
    return PlaybackState(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.rewind,
        if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.stop,
        MediaControl.fastForward,
      ],
      systemActions: const {
        MediaAction.seek,
        MediaAction.seekForward,
        MediaAction.seekBackward,
      },
      androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
      processingState: const {
        ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
        ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
        ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
        ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
        ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
      }[_player.processingState]!,
      playing: _player.playing,
      updatePosition: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
      queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
    );
  }

}
```

I am trying to create an alarm functionality using `android_alarm_manager_plus`:

```
main.dart:

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  _audioHandler = await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => IsolatedAudioHandler(AudioPlayerHandler(), portName: 'my_audio_handler'),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.ryanheise.myapp.channel.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

```
AlarmPage.dart
 void _setAlarm10Seconds() async {
    final a = await IsolatedAudioHandler.lookup(
      portName: 'my_audio_handler',
    );
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      const Duration(seconds: 10),
      // Ensure we have a unique alarm ID.
      Random().nextInt(pow(2, 31) as int),
      callback,
      exact: true,
      wakeup: true,
    );
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static callback() {
    print("Alarm fired");
    final AudioHandler handler = await IsolatedAudioHandler.lookup(
      portName: 'my_audio_handler',
    );
    handler.play();
  }
```

When trying to get the audio handler from `callback` I get error:

`Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: is a regular instance reachable via : Instance of '_IsolateRequest'`

Using the same logic of getting the audio handler works if I do that from a widget for example, but not from a static method. How can I access the handler from the static method?

I tried getting AudioPlayerHandler's static instance from callback. It did not output any errors but it did not play any sound either.